# E/Volley: [2458] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL

Tags: android, kotlin, http-post, android-volley

I'm trying to connect to database server via android.

My question is can I somehow use localhost url like this:

```
private const val ROOT_URL = "http://localhost/android/v1/"
```

Instead of providing my computer's IP address? This is my school project and I have some concerns when I present it something will not work because of the different IP.

I've already tested it like this:

```
private const val ROOT_URL = "http://IP/android/v1/"
```

And everything works. So my only question is can I replace the IP address with something static that doesn't need to be changed when I connect to another Wi-Fi network

There is errorlog when I use 'http://localhost/android/v1/' or 'https://localhost/android/v1/':

```
E/Volley: [2503] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL localhost/android/v1/userLogin.php
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL localhost/android/v1/userLogin.php
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:175)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
 Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: localhost/android/v1/userLogin.php
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:601)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:498)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:447)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:87)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131) 
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111) 
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use IP in this case.

Comment: Use "https://" instead of "http://"

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna I posted errorlog after using https, same result

Comment: Then its problem with your URL route! run the url with postman first, be sure if it works or not and then go with volley!

Comment: @EmonHossainMunna I checked the url with PostMan and everything seems to work